# How to ignore returning None in re.search Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and a list of two elements that by using a custom `def` I yield different versions of each element by one mismatch - then I do a loop to perform `re.search` and if any version of elements founded then print that part on the main string.

My code is working but not my challenge is to skip `None` in `re.search`.

Here is my code:

```
list=['patterrn1','pattern2']
my_string='something--patterRn1--something'

def idf_one_mismatch(x):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        yield x[:i] + '.' + x[i+1:]

def find_while_mismatch(x,y):
    for i in idf_one_mismatch(x):
        m = re.search(i,str(y))
        if m is not None: 
            return m.group()

for i in list:
    idf1 = find_while_mismatch(i, my_string)
    print(idf1)
```

The output is:

```
patterRn1
None
```

Which the output should skip the `None` but it does not. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Function `find_while_mismatch` will return None if the for loop is exhausted.  You need to check if `idf1 ` is None before printing.

Comment: And what do you want to return if there is no match found? If nothing, just use`if idf1: print(idf1)` instead of  `print(idf1)` as the last line in your snippet.

Comment: ouch: overriding `list` with a variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, do not use reserved words / builtins as variable names, replace `list` with some other name.

Second, you get `None` since your `find_while_mismatch` returns this value if no match was found during the `for` loop.

Use

```py
if idf1:
    print(idf1)
```

if you need to prevent that output.